# Apache php app with rewrites, to serve independent files on /mydir

Tags: rewrite, apache2

I've installed a php application (dokuwiki) on the / path of my apache server, but I wish to serve some different files (different files than those from dokuwiki I mean) on certain /mydir path.

Currently, /mydir just pops a non-existent page on my dokuwiki installation, but I wish to serve something very different than dokuwiki contents here.

I have dokuwiki installed on my server at /var/web/dokuwiki
And have my files I wish to serve at /var/www/mydir

Is there a way to configure Apache to serve my files without interfering with dokuwiki and viceversa?

current dokuwiki rewrite rules live on .htaccess :

```
## Enable this to restrict editing to logged in users only

# You should disable Indexes and MultiViews either here or in the
# global config. Symlinks maybe needed for URL rewriting.
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

# make sure nobody gets the htaccess, README, COPYING or VERSION files
<Files ~ "^([\._]ht|README$|VERSION$|COPYING$)">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Uncomment these rules if you want to have nice URLs using
# $conf['userewrite'] = 1 - not needed for rewrite mode 2
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^_media/(.*)              lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_detail/(.*)             lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^_export/([^/]+)/(.*)     doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^$                        doku.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d
RewriteRule (.*)                      doku.php?id=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$               doku.php

# Not all installations will require the following line.  If you do,
# change "/dokuwiki" to the path to your dokuwiki directory relative
# to your document root.
RewriteBase /

# If you enable DokuWikis XML-RPC interface, you should consider to
# restrict access to it over HTTPS only! Uncomment the following two
# rules if your server setup allows HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^lib/exe/xmlrpc.php$      https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a simple `Alias /mydir/ /var/www/mydir/`? You may need a  directive to allow access to `/var/www/mydir`, but otherwise this will just work.
You can even put your Alias into the webserver configuration so you don't have to interfere with your wiki installation.